# How do I copy what I enter into 'InputField' without any computational processing?

Tags: string-manipulation, inputfied, holdform

I made an InputField where I input the quoted sentences inside.
And I set InputField to copy every time I run it.

```
Manipulate[Column[show], 
Style[Control@{{in, "1+1"}, InputField[#] &, ImageSize -> 200 }, 20],
Button["Evaluate", { CopyToClipboard[
RawBoxes@FrontEndExecute@FrontEnd`ReparseBoxStructurePacket@in],    
show = { in, ToExpression[in]} }  ], 
ContinuousAction -> False, AppearanceElements -> None, 
Initialization :> (show = {})]
```

As shown in the screen below, it works well within quotation marks.

[image]

However, I would like the same InputField value to be copied as you input even when there is no quotation mark.
For example, if I type 1+2+3, I want 1+2+3 to be copied, not 6. How do I write an additional code?

Comment: Try: `InputField[#, String]`

Comment: Well... I need to succeed at it while keeping InputField[#] intact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the [`Boxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Boxes) type, e.g.:

```
Manipulate[
    Column[show],
    Style[Control @ {{in, MakeBoxes[1+1]}, InputField[#,Boxes]&, ImageSize->200}, 20],
    Button[
        "Evaluate",
        {
            CopyToClipboard[RawBoxes@in],
            show = {RawBoxes@in, ToExpression[in]}
        }
    ],
    ContinuousAction->False,
    AppearanceElements->None,
    Initialization:>(show={})
]
```

Comment: Thank you. With your response, I have solved many related problems.